# The first query is always slower

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 6  with SQL server 2008R2

I have this problem :

- The first query executed against an entity is very slow. All the next queries against the same entity are very fast.
- The same thing with other entities , the first query is always slower.

I try with pre generated views , but it's the same problem.
What can I do ?

Comment: executing same query secnd time ?

Comment: Second time , I can execute any kind of query and it's faster , even a query than read 10 times more records that the first time , it's many times faster.

Comment: even a simple query taking time first time ?..First time mean ? after starting server ? or after boot system ?

Comment: even a simpler query that read only 1 record , when is executed for the first time takes a lot's of time.